# Precalculus Distance/Rate/Time

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If someone can drive to Chicago in 82 minutes and drove back in 96 minutes . What were her speeds if her speed coming back was 5 miles per hour less than her speed going there.

I was just wondering if I need to convert the minutes to hours or if it matters?

Comment: Would I be going faster if I were driving 60 mi./hr., or 60 mi./min. or does it matter?

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to be sure you are right if you make the units match.  Let the distance to Chicago be $D$ miles, then compute the speeds.  As you need the difference to be $5$ miles/hour, you need to subtract speeds that are in miles/hour.  In this problem, you can essentially multiply by 60 minutes per hour and it divides out, so here you are OK. I find it harder to work through this than to just get the units right.

Comment: If distance = (rate)(time). Then 82x = 96(x - 5). If you solve that you get 34.286. If you convert the minutes to hours don't you get the same answer?

Comment: I see that.  You can essentially multiply by 60 minutes per hour and it divides out, so here you are OK.  I find it harder to work through this than to just get the units right.

Answer (score 0):

No you needn't convert the units in fact. This is because the units get cancelled out in this case.

Let $x$ be the forward speed. $82(x)=96(x-5)$  $x=34.286 miles/hour$

Note, this is only in this case though! It is because the units got cancelled out. In other cases, just make sure to put all distances in the same unit, all speeds in the same unit and all time in the same unit. Then you can surely work without changing everything to the same unit.